# Distribute data into buckets based on sales

Tags: sql-server, bucket

I am have been working to come up with a solution that would create 5 buckets of equal sales for customers within a region. I attempted to use a while loop as well as a cursor to no avail. In which I define the total sales and then divide the sales by 5 to come up with the sales amount for each bucket.

As an example if the total sales was $100,000 the bucket size would be $20,000. The loop would take the customers starting with the lowest to highest sales and begin filling bucket 1, once the combined sales for the those customers assigned to bucket 2 exceeded $20,000, the same process would be repeated to assign the remaining customers to bucket 3-5.

Here's some code to generate the sample data:

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#Customer') is not null
drop table #Customer;

CREATE TABLE #Customer(
 CustomerID int
,Region varchar(30)
,Sales money
)

INSERT INTO #Customer Select '1', 'East', '0'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '2', 'East', '20'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '3', 'East', '40'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '4', 'East', '60'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '5', 'East', '80'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '6', 'East', '100'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '7', 'East', '120'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '8', 'East', '140'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '9', 'East', '160'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '10', 'East', '180'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '11', 'East', '200'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '12', 'East', '220'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '13', 'East', '240'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '14', 'East', '260'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '15', 'East', '280'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '16', 'East', '300'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '17', 'East', '320'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '18', 'East', '340'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '19', 'East', '360'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '20', 'East', '380'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '21', 'East', '400'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '22', 'East', '420'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '23', 'East', '440'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '24', 'East', '460'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '25', 'East', '480'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '26', 'East', '500'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '27', 'East', '520'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '28', 'East', '540'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '29', 'East', '560'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '30', 'East', '580'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '31', 'East', '600'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '32', 'East', '620'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '33', 'East', '640'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '34', 'East', '660'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '35', 'East', '680'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '36', 'East', '700'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '37', 'East', '720'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '38', 'East', '740'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '39', 'East', '760'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '40', 'East', '780'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '41', 'East', '800'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '42', 'East', '820'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '43', 'East', '840'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '44', 'East', '860'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '45', 'East', '880'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '46', 'East', '900'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '47', 'East', '920'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '48', 'East', '940'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '49', 'East', '960'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '50', 'East', '980'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '51', 'East', '1000'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '52', 'East', '1020'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '53', 'East', '1040'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '54', 'East', '1060'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '55', 'East', '1080'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '56', 'East', '1100'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '57', 'East', '1120'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '58', 'East', '1140'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '59', 'East', '1160'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '60', 'East', '1180'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '61', 'East', '1200'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '62', 'East', '1220'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '63', 'East', '1240'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '64', 'East', '1260'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '65', 'East', '1280'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '66', 'East', '1300'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '67', 'East', '1320'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '68', 'East', '1340'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '69', 'East', '1360'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '70', 'East', '1380'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '71', 'East', '1400'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '72', 'East', '1420'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '73', 'East', '1440'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '74', 'East', '1460'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '75', 'East', '1480'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '76', 'East', '1500'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '77', 'East', '1520'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '78', 'East', '1540'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '79', 'East', '1560'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '80', 'East', '1580'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '81', 'East', '1600'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '82', 'East', '1620'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '83', 'East', '1640'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '84', 'East', '1660'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '85', 'East', '1680'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '86', 'East', '1700'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '87', 'East', '1720'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '88', 'East', '1740'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '89', 'East', '1760'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '90', 'East', '1780'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '91', 'East', '1800'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '92', 'East', '1820'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '93', 'East', '1840'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '94', 'East', '1860'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '95', 'East', '1880'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '96', 'East', '1900'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '97', 'East', '1920'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '98', 'East', '1940'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '99', 'East', '1960'
INSERT INTO #Customer Select '100', 'East', '2980'
```

Here is the logic I am currently using which works fine for one Region, but when I try to include another region the logic applies the buckets using the total sales from both regions to calculate the buckets.

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#rank') is not null
    drop table #rank;

create table #rank (
     customer_Id int
    , region varchar(30)
    , sales money
    , sales_rank int
    , bucket int
    );

insert into #rank
select x.*
    , row_number() over (order by x.sales desc) as sales_rank
    , null as bucket
from #customer x;



declare @region_sales money, @bucket_amt money, @ctr int, @running_total money, @customer_id int, @sales money;
set @region_sales = (select sum(sales) from #customer);
set @bucket_amt = @region_sales / 5;
set @running_total = 0
set @ctr = 1

declare csr cursor forward_only for
select customer_id, sales from #rank order by sales_rank desc;
open csr
fetch next from csr into @customer_id, @sales
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
    if @running_total <= @bucket_amt
        begin
            set @running_total = @running_total + @sales;
            update x set x.bucket = @ctr from #rank x where x.customer_id = @customer_id;
        end
    else
        begin
            set @running_total = 0
            set @ctr = @ctr + 1
            update x set x.bucket = @ctr from #rank x where x.customer_id = @customer_id;
        end
    fetch next from csr into @customer_id, @sales
    end
close csr;
deallocate csr;
```

How can I modify the logic to create the buckets individually for each region?

I am open to any additional methods other than using a cursor as this method can be slow with large volume of data.

Using the same data above and duplicating the records inserted for the East Region and changing the duplicated records to West Region (with the same customers and values) the end result of this logic would produce these results.

```
select Region, bucket, sum(sales) as Total_Sales from #rank
Group by Region, bucket
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NTILE is what I think you're looking for. Try the following code:

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Customer') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #Customer;
END;

CREATE TABLE #Customer
(
CustomerID int,
Region varchar(30),
Sales decimal(18, 2)
);

INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (1, 'East', 0);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (2, 'East', 20);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (3, 'East', 40);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (4, 'East', 60);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (5, 'East', 80);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (6, 'East', 100);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (7, 'East', 120);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (8, 'East', 140);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (9, 'East', 160);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (10, 'East', 180);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (11, 'East', 200);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (12, 'East', 220);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (13, 'East', 240);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (14, 'East', 260);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (15, 'East', 280);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (16, 'East', 300);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (17, 'East', 320);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (18, 'East', 340);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (19, 'East', 360);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (20, 'East', 380);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (21, 'East', 400);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (22, 'East', 420);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (23, 'East', 440);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (24, 'East', 460);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (25, 'East', 480);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (26, 'East', 500);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (27, 'East', 520);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (28, 'East', 540);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (29, 'East', 560);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (30, 'East', 580);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (31, 'East', 600);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (32, 'East', 620);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (33, 'East', 640);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (34, 'East', 660);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (35, 'East', 680);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (36, 'East', 700);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (37, 'East', 720);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (38, 'East', 740);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (39, 'East', 760);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (40, 'East', 780);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (41, 'East', 800);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (42, 'East', 820);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (43, 'East', 840);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (44, 'East', 860);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (45, 'East', 880);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (46, 'East', 900);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (47, 'East', 920);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (48, 'East', 940);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (49, 'East', 960);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (50, 'East', 980);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (51, 'East', 1000);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (52, 'East', 1020);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (53, 'East', 1040);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (54, 'East', 1060);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (55, 'East', 1080);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (56, 'East', 1100);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (57, 'East', 1120);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (58, 'East', 1140);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (59, 'East', 1160);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (60, 'East', 1180);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (61, 'East', 1200);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (62, 'East', 1220);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (63, 'East', 1240);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (64, 'East', 1260);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (65, 'East', 1280);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (66, 'East', 1300);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (67, 'East', 1320);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (68, 'East', 1340);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (69, 'East', 1360);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (70, 'East', 1380);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (71, 'East', 1400);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (72, 'East', 1420);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (73, 'East', 1440);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (74, 'East', 1460);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (75, 'East', 1480);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (76, 'East', 1500);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (77, 'East', 1520);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (78, 'East', 1540);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (79, 'East', 1560);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (80, 'East', 1580);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (81, 'East', 1600);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (82, 'East', 1620);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (83, 'East', 1640);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (84, 'East', 1660);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (85, 'East', 1680);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (86, 'East', 1700);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (87, 'East', 1720);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (88, 'East', 1740);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (89, 'East', 1760);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (90, 'East', 1780);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (91, 'East', 1800);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (92, 'East', 1820);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (93, 'East', 1840);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (94, 'East', 1860);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (95, 'East', 1880);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (96, 'East', 1900);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (97, 'East', 1920);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (98, 'East', 1940);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (99, 'East', 1960);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES (100, 'East', 2980);

INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(101, 'West', 0);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(102, 'West', 20);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(103, 'West', 40);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(104, 'West', 60);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(105, 'West', 80);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(106, 'West', 100);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(107, 'West', 120);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(108, 'West', 140);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(109, 'West', 160);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(110, 'West', 180);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(111, 'West', 200);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(112, 'West', 220);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(113, 'West', 240);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(114, 'West', 260);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(115, 'West', 280);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(116, 'West', 300);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(117, 'West', 320);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(118, 'West', 340);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(119, 'West', 360);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(120, 'West', 380);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(121, 'West', 400);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(122, 'West', 420);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(123, 'West', 440);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(124, 'West', 460);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(125, 'West', 480);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(126, 'West', 500);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(127, 'West', 520);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(128, 'West', 540);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(129, 'West', 560);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(130, 'West', 580);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(131, 'West', 600);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(132, 'West', 620);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(133, 'West', 640);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(134, 'West', 660);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(135, 'West', 680);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(136, 'West', 700);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(137, 'West', 720);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(138, 'West', 740);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(139, 'West', 760);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(140, 'West', 780);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(141, 'West', 800);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(142, 'West', 820);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(143, 'West', 840);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(144, 'West', 860);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(145, 'West', 880);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(146, 'West', 900);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(147, 'West', 920);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(148, 'West', 940);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(149, 'West', 960);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(150, 'West', 980);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(151, 'West', 1000);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(152, 'West', 1020);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(153, 'West', 1040);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(154, 'West', 1060);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(155, 'West', 1080);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(156, 'West', 1100);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(157, 'West', 1120);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(158, 'West', 1140);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(159, 'West', 1160);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(160, 'West', 1180);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(161, 'West', 1200);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(162, 'West', 1220);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(163, 'West', 1240);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(164, 'West', 1260);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(165, 'West', 1280);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(166, 'West', 1300);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(167, 'West', 1320);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(168, 'West', 1340);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(169, 'West', 1360);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(170, 'West', 1380);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(171, 'West', 1400);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(172, 'West', 1420);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(173, 'West', 1440);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(174, 'West', 1460);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(175, 'West', 1480);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(176, 'West', 1500);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(177, 'West', 1520);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(178, 'West', 1540);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(179, 'West', 1560);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(180, 'West', 1580);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(181, 'West', 1600);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(182, 'West', 1620);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(183, 'West', 1640);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(184, 'West', 1660);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(185, 'West', 1680);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(186, 'West', 1700);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(187, 'West', 1720);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(188, 'West', 1740);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(189, 'West', 1760);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(190, 'West', 1780);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(191, 'West', 1800);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(192, 'West', 1820);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(193, 'West', 1840);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(194, 'West', 1860);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(195, 'West', 1880);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(196, 'West', 1900);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(197, 'West', 1920);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(198, 'West', 1940);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(199, 'West', 1960);
INSERT INTO #Customer(CustomerID, Region, Sales) VALUES(200, 'West', 2980);

SELECT CustomerID, Region, Sales,
NTILE(5) OVER(PARTITION BY Region ORDER BY Sales DESC) AS Bucket
FROM #Customer;

Comment: Thank you Greg! I tried NTILE but the results differ from what I am looking for. When I used the cursor method it produces equivalent buckets of sales. For East region I get Bucket 1 with $20,700, Bucket 2 with $22,200, Bucket 3 with $21,900, Bucket 4 with $22,620, Bucket 5 with $12,580. As the logic fills each of the buckets until the bucket value exceeds one fifth of the total sales value. The NTILE creates the buckets based on an even distribution of customers vs. even distribution of sales so for the East region all 5 buckets have 20 customers.

Comment: Gotchya. Thought you were spreading the number of customers, not the total sales for the group of customers.